# How to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement

Tags: java, syntax, if-statement

I have an if statement with many conditions (have to check for 10 or 15 constants to see if any of them are present.)

Instead of writing something like:

```
if (x == 12 || x == 16 || x == 19 || ...)
```

is there any way to format it like

```
if x is [12, 16, 19]?
```

I was making a date validation class that needed to make sure days were not > 30 in the months that have only 30 days (of which there are 4, I think) and I was writing an if statement to check things like this:

```
if (day > 30 && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))
```

Is there another way to write this that is less verbose/more efficient?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I use this kind of pattern often. It's very compact:

Define a constant in your class:

```
private static final Set<Integer> VALUES = Set.of(12, 16, 19);    
// Pre Java 9 use: VALUES = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(12, 16, 19));
```

In your method:

```
if (VALUES.contains(x)) {
    ...
}
```

`Set.of()` returns a `HashSet`, which performs very well even for very large sets.

If performance is not important, you can code the gist of it into one line for less code footprint:

```
if (Set.of(12, 16, 19).contains(x))
```

but know that it will create a new `Set` every time it executes.

Comment: if (Arrays.asList(12, 16, 19).contains(x))

Comment: I'd rather use a `Set` than a `List` for this, but that's won't really have any effect on that few elements.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Incorporated your idea - it's a good one too! HashSet is gonna be way faster

Comment: [Using Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html):
`private static final ImmutableSet<Integer> values = ImmutableSet.of(12, 16, 19);`

Comment: Note: Since Java 9 the `Set.of()` method allows this to be simplified to `Set<Integer> values = Set.of(12, 16, 19)` (basically the same as Guava, except Guava is no longer needed).

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks. Answer modernised.

Answer (score 12):

Do you want to switch to this??

```
switch(x) {
    case 12:
    case 16:
    case 19: 
        //Do something
        break;
    default:
        //Do nothing or something else..
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could look for the presence of a map key or see if it's in a set.

Depending on what you're actually *doing*, though, you might be trying to solve the problem wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a collection of some sort - this will make the code more readable and hide away all those constants. A simple way would be with a list:

```
// Declared with constants
private static List<Integer> myConstants = new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
    add(12);
    add(16);
    add(19);
}};

// Wherever you are checking for presence of the constant
if(myConstants.contains(x)){
    // ETC
}
```

As Bohemian points out the list of constants can be static so it's accessible in more than one place.

For anyone interested, the list in my example is using [double brace initialization](http://kzeil.home.xs4all.nl/en/project/java/initializer-block.html). Since I ran into it recently I've found it nice for writing quick & dirty list initializations.

Comment: or `if(Arrays.asList(new int[]{12,16,19}).contains(x)){ ... }`

Comment: @Bala sure! In any case a list is just an example of a collection to use here. As one of the other answers suggested a set might be better to ensure the constants are unique... Or a hash table to speed up look up, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If the set of possibilities is "compact" (i.e. largest-value - smallest-value is, say, less than 200) you might consider a lookup table.  This would be especially useful if you had a structure like

```
if (x == 12 || x == 16 || x == 19 || ...)
else if (x==34 || x == 55 || ...)
else if (...)
```

Set up an array with values identifying the branch to be taken (1, 2, 3 in the example above) and then your tests become

```
switch(dispatchTable[x])
{
    case 1:
        ...
        break;
    case 2:
        ...
        break;
    case 3:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Whether or not this is appropriate depends on the semantics of the problem.

If an array isn't appropriate, you could use a `Map<Integer,Integer>`, or if you just want to test membership for a single statement, a `Set<Integer>` would do.  That's a lot of firepower for a simple `if` statement, however, so without more context it's kind of hard to guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot do that in Java. you can however write a method as follows:

```
boolean isContains(int i, int ... numbers) {
    // code to check if i is one of the numbers
    for (int n : numbers) {
        if (i == n) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, you could use a primitive stream:

```
if (IntStream.of(12, 16, 19).anyMatch(i -> i == x))
```

but this may have a slight overhead (or not), depending on the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer based on a comment above, but simpler:

```
List numbers= Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
if(numbers.contains(x)){
     //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java8 there is another approach using Stream.of:

```
Stream.of(a==1, b.equals("something"), c > 23, rocket.wasFired()).anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)
```

When there are multiple conditions you have to check save some code lines.

I think that conceptually is better, because the main purpose is to check if a multiple or compound predicate is true, instead of check the existence of an element in a container.

In the main question case, could be as follows:

```
Stream.of(month == 4, month == 6, month == 9, month == 11).anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals)
```