# Best DRY if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, dry

Let's say I want to compare a bunch of variables to one static variable, normally I would do it like this:

```
int w = 0;
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 2;
if(w == x || w == y || w == z){/*more code here*/}
```

But that can get extremely long and doesn't seem necessary, are there any ways to do something more like:

```
 if(w == (x || y || z)){/*more code here*/}
```

I would like to think that there is a way to do it like this.

Comment: Java does not provide this natively in its syntax.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not in a clean way anyways

Comment: You can get some insight from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/best-way-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement-java

Comment: @JimGarrison I wanted to avoid doing something like that, really all I'm trying to do is keep things concise, while still getting the job done in a non-hackish way.

Comment: @Junaid Thanks, I didn't see that one when I searched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if(w == x || w == y || w == z)
```

you can do:

```
if(Arrays.asList(x, y, z).contains(w))
```

Comment: But orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: @EJP You know what they say *Premature optimization is the root of all evil* so as long as this is not one of the application's bottleneck I think it should not be a relevant factor.

Answer (score 3):

Though there is an answer accepted, I would want to share my ways too:

Method 1 is similar to the accepted answer.  However, instead of using List, I use a Set.  In such case, it may be even faster than doing `==` individually if there are lots of values to check against:

```
// make it a static final member if semantically possible
Set<Integer> ALL_VALUES = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h));

//.....

if (ALL_VALUES.contains(w)) {
  //... do something
}
```

Method 2 is to write a little utility function, something like

```
public static <T> boolean sameAsAny(T value, T... possibleValues) {
  for (T p : possibleValues) {
    if (value == p) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

with such util you can do something like:

```
if (sameAsAny(w, x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might prefer to format it like this :

```
if(w == x ||
   w == y ||
   w == z)
```

I find it helps break up the conditions and makes it easier to read.

Comment: This isn't what the OP is looking for. All you've done is reformatted a few lines...

Answer (score 0):

That is not allowed in Java. But you could look into some rules based engines e.g [drools](http://www.mastertheboss.com/drools/jboss-drools-tutorial).