# "or" conditions of various strings within an if...then statement

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I'm practicing writing code in Java and am working on a simple program that asks which class (from Dungeons and Dragons) the user is wanting to be. After that data is received I want my next question to bring up a list of weapons based on the entered class.

My problem lies within the first question "Greeting, hero...". When the user inputs an invalid class I would like for a message to pop up stating that a proper class needs to be chosen, and then a list of different classes appears for the user. I'm not sure how to properly write the "if..then" statement.

This program is incomplete and I stopped at the part I was stuck on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class apples {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner uinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstclass, secondclass, multiclass, rogue, bard, fighter, wizard, sorcerer, monk, paladin, cleric, warlock, ranger;
        int dagger, shortsword, mace;

        System.out.println("Greetings hero, what profession do others call you?");
        firstclass = uinput.next();
        if(firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("rogue") || ("bard") || "fighter" || "wizard" || "sorcerer" || "monk" || "paladin" || "cleric" || "warlock" || "ranger"));

        System.out.println("Aha! So we have a " +firstclass + " in our party!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the right way. You either repeat the`firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase` for each string, or use `switch`, or - preferably - use a `Set<String>` and test for inclusion.

Comment: `"fighter"`, `"wizard"`, etc. aren't boolean expressions.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/best-way-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement-java) for good ways to evaluate multiple conditions.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm brand new to this and am teaching myself with sources I'm finding online. I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the most straightforward way to write the code, though as others have pointed out, you'll probably want to put all the "known" classes into a `Set<String>` so you can easily test whether the input is in the set and so you can also easily print out all the valid options.

```
if(firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("rogue") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("bard") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("fighter") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("wizard") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("sorcerer") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("monk") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("paladin") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("cleric") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("warlock") || firstclass.equalsIgnoreCase("ranger")) {
    System.out.println("Aha! So we have a " + firstclass + " in our party!");
} else {
    System.out.println("I don't know what a " + firstclass + " is.");
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much.  I feel ashamed for asking such a basic question but I'm teaching myself java with whatever I'm finding online. Your help is greatly appreciated.