# How can I create an if statement with 3 conditions? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I just started learning java a week ago. I am taking a class at my school. I am trying to create a quiz and I can't figure out how to print out the score. The quiz has three possibilities 3/3, 2/3, 1/3. The problem I am having is with the if statements near the end of the program.

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

class t1_lesson03_template{


     public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException {

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("1. What do you type at the begining of a comment?");
       String answer1 = "//";
       String userinput1 = scan.nextLine();

       if (userinput1.equals(answer1)) {
          System.out.println(" Correct!");
       }
       if (!userinput1.equals(answer1)) {
       System.out.println(" Wrong!");
       }
       String answer2 = ("(int)");

       System.out.println("2. What do you type before a double to convert to an int?");
       String userinput2 = scan.nextLine();
       if (userinput2.equals(answer2)) {
         System.out.println(" Correct!");
       }
       if (!userinput2.equals(answer2)) {
         System.out.println(" Wrong!");
       }
       String answer3 = ("int number = 5;");

       System.out.println("3. Create an int called \"number\", and make it equal 5.");
       String userinput3 = scan.nextLine();
       if (userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
         System.out.println(" Correct!");
       }
       if (!userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
        System.out.println(" Wrong!"); 
       }
       if (userinput1.equals(answer1)  && userinput2.equals(answer2)  && userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
         System.out.println("3/3 Awesome!");
       }
       else if (userinput1.equals(answer1) || userinput2.equals(answer2) || userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
         System.out.println("2/3 Good job.");
       }   
       else {
         System.out.println("1/3 Try again.");
       }   

     }

}
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/best-way-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This,

```
else if (userinput1.equals(answer1) || userinput2.equals(answer2) 
    || userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
```

should be something like

```
else if ((userinput1.equals(answer1) && userinput2.equals(answer2)) ||
         (userinput1.equals(answer1) && userinput3.equals(answer3)) ||
         (userinput2.equals(answer2) && userinput3.equals(answer3))) {
```

**but** I would prefer a `count`. And an array to display your different messages. Something like

```
int count = 0;
if (userinput1.equals(answer1)) {
    count++;
}
if (userinput2.equals(answer2)) {
    count++;
}
if (userinput3.equals(answer3)) {
    count++;
}
String[] result = { "0/3 None", "1/3 Try Again.", "2/3 Good Job.", "3/3 Awesome!" };
System.out.println(result[count]);
```

Comment: Note that the fundamental structure of the "count" approach is unchanged when even more questions are added - hence this a much better solution than the complex boolean (&& ||) solution. A further improvement would be to put the inputs and answers in arrays and check them in a loop. Then nothing changes when more questions are added.

Answer (score -2):

Just add braces before each condition in if class and else if such as

```
if ((userinput1.equals(answer1))  && (userinput2.equals(answer2))  && (userinput3.equals(answer3))) {
    System.out.println("3/3 Awesome!");
}
else if ((userinput1.equals(answer1)) || (userinput2.equals(answer2)) || (userinput3.equals(answer3))) {
    System.out.println("2/3 Good job.");
}
```

Comment: The ( 1 || 2 || 3 ) will also be true if only one of the three answers is right.