# Java Nested If statement-Or Compared to !=

Tags: java, if-statement

I wasn't sure how to give a title for this problem, but basically this is part of my blackjack program. Also, since I did not know how to title this, I wasn't sure how to look it up, which is why I am asking here. So I am saying that when the user enters either 1 or 11 for the ace value, if they enter something other than 1 or 11, it asks the user again to put in 1 or 11. In my program everything works fine except when the user enters 1, then it just asks the question again. The program should only asks again if the input is not equal to 1 or 11. Here is my code as I made sure it always gives an ace for testing purposes:

```
String card1="A";
int total=0;
Scanner input_var=new Scanner(System.in);
if (card1=="A"){
    System.out.println("Do you want a 1 or 11 for the Ace?: ");
    int player_ace_selection=input_var.nextInt();
    if ((1|11)!=(player_ace_selection)){
        System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or 11: ");
        int new_selection=input_var.nextInt();
        total=total + new_selection;
    }
    else {
        total=total + player_ace_selection;
    }
}
System.out.println(total);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `.nextInt()` vs `.nextLine` -> the first doesn't read the new line `\n`

Comment: There is no short form `OR`, you are doing a bitwise or on `1` and `11` at `(1|11)!=(player_ace_selection)`

Comment: `card1 == "A"` is not the only problem here, and it's not the main one. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Also use `.equals()` instead of `==` for comparing Strings i.e. `card1` and `"A"`

Comment: See [best way to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/best-way-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement-java) and [how do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an If statement, try a while loop. A while loop ensures that your program waits for your user to pick the right answer. You also made a mistake with your logical operations. The correct way to use "OR" in this context is to compare your user input to both '1' and '11' separately using '||'.

```
    String card1="A";
    int total=0;
    Scanner input_var=new Scanner(System.in);
    if (card1.equals("A")){
        System.out.println("Do you want a 1 or 11 for the Ace?: ");
        int player_ace_selection=input_var.nextInt();

        while(player_ace_selection != 1 && player_ace_selection != 11){
            System.out.println("Do you want a 1 or 11 for the Ace?: ");
            player_ace_selection = input_var.nextInt();                
        }
        total += player_ace_selection;
    }

    System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: You have a great error in your code, the `while` loop never stops!

Comment: What condition would satisfy your `while` loop?

Comment: Your answer keeps asking the question if user gets it wrong the first time but gets it right the second time.

Comment: Fixed it. The condition in the while loop should have been an AND instead of OR.

Comment: Thanks, this time it worked correctly. I will go back and look at why and hows.

Comment: I see the couple of small things I could have done better and the big thing to now. Thanks so much.

Comment: @BobG. And don't care if your user enters any non-digit input and crashes your program! added to that the infinite `while` loop, it can be a cool game for the user! Thumb up, Go ahead !!

Answer (score 3):

The expression `(1|11)` uses binary `OR`, which produces `11`:

```
    11 = 01001
     1 = 00001
(11|1) = 01001
```

Hence, the comparison is the same as `11!=player_ace_selection`

You should change the code to use logical `OR`, i.e.

```
if (1!=player_ace_selection && 11!=player_ace_selection) {
    ...
}
```

In addition, you need to fix `card1 == "A"` comparison for `card1.equals("A")`

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code, please consider this example and compare it with yours.

```
String card1="A";
int total=0;
Scanner input_var=new Scanner(System.in);
if (card1.equals("A")){ // compare the content not the reference (==)
   System.out.println("Do you want a 1 or 11 for the Ace?: ");
   try{ // wrap with try-catch block
       int player_ace_selection = Integer.parseInt(input_var.nextLine()); //read the entire line and parse the input
       if ((player_ace_selection!=1)&&(player_ace_selection!=11)){
             System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or 11: ");
             try{
                int new_selection = Integer.parseInt(input_var.nextLine()); //again read the entire line and parse the input
                total=total + new_selection;
             }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                   // do something to catch the error
             }
        }
        else {
             total=total + player_ace_selection;

        }

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
             // do something to catch the error
    }
    System.out.println(total);

}
```