# What is the best way to refactor multiple conditions in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an if statement with lots of conditions inside, but the conditions are fairly different. It looks really bulky. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it.

```java
// rqstCriteria is a List
// anotherCriteria is a List
// key# are the different values that I want to see if it has
if (
rqstCriteria.contains(key1) || 
rqstCriteria.contains(key2) || 
rqstCriteria.contains(key3) || 
rqstCriteria.contains(key4) || 
rqstCriteria.contains(key5) && 
(anotherCriteria != null && 
  (anotherCriteria.contains(key1) || 
   anotherCriteria.contains(key2) || 
   anotherCriteria.contains(key3) || 
   anotherCriteria.contains(key4) || 
   anotherCriteria.contains(key5))
{...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/best-way-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement-java) use this for each of your lists, and then make a smaller if-tree

Comment: `if (rqstCriteria.stream().anyMatch(keySet::contains)` etc, where `keySet = Set.of(key1, key2, ...)`.

Comment: The example looks strange having `rqstCriteria.contains(key5) &&` not `(rqstCriteria.contains(key1) ... rqstCriteria.contains(key5) ) &&`. Is it a typo or part of the question -- to have those checks exactly like that?

Answer (score 1):

First collect all the keys into list and using java-8 `streams.anyMatch`

```
List<String> list = List.of("key1","key2");  //or Arrays.asList()

if(list.stream().anyMatch(i->rqstCriteria.contains(i)) && list.stream().anyMatch(j->anotherCriteria.contains(j))) {

}
```

And i would say to move out the `null` check to outside of `if` block, best way is to return empty `List` or you can use the below approach

```
if(list.stream().anyMatch(i->rqstCriteria.contains(i)) && 
        Objects.nonNull(anotherCriteria) && 
        list.stream().anyMatch(j->anotherCriteria.contains(j))) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a helper method `containsAny` (thanks to @chrylis for optimizing it):

```
public <T> boolean containsAny(Collection<T> c, T... keys) {
    return c != null && Arrays.stream(keys).anyMatch(c::contains);
}
```

And then use it in your if statements:

```
if (containsAny(rqstCriteria, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5) 
    && containsAny(anotherCriteria, key1, key2, key3, key4, key5)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(keys)` would be a lot cheaper than copying into a `HashSet`.

Comment: @chrylis I completely agree, thank you

Answer (score 0):

'''short-and-unhelpful-answer'''': Rethink your model to not require multiple if-statements.

'''not-so-longger-but-insightfull-and-pragmmatic-answer'': Create a hierarchy of classes where each one describes an entity that would have the properties tested on each relevant If-case.

class Stuffy would be of objects that fulfill, by definition, the requirements to match if-1. Thingy would be the same about if-2... All of them would implement Anything...

Then, instead of your big ugly doIt() method with a dirty-ugly if, each concrete class would implement its own doIt() (with the code you would put on every ifX clause).

Answer (score 0):

I think your condition is strange.  But

```
if (Stream.of(key1, key2, key3, key4).anyMatch(rqstCriteria::contains) ||
    rqstCriteria.contains(key5) && 
    anotherCriteria != null && 
    Stream.of(key1, key2, key3, key4, key5).anyMatch(anotherCriteria::contains))
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add one more approach using predicates:

Assuming your criteria lists store strings, create a set containing your keys:

```
Set<String> myKeys = Set.of("key1","key2","key3","key4","key5");
```

and two predicates which accept a list

```
Predicate<List<String>> containsOneOfMyKeys = l -> l.stream().anyMatch(s -> myKeys.contains(s));
Predicate<List<String>> isNotNullOrEmpty = l -> Objects.nonNull(l) && !l.isEmpty();
```

Then you could simplify your if statement in a readable way like:

```
if(containsOneOfMyKeys.test(rqstCriteria) &&
   isNotNullOrEmpty.and(containsOneOfMyKeys).test(anotherCriteria)){
   //do something
}
```