# Should I use Arrays or the OR function?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am new to java and want to learn more about optimization. As such in a project I am working on I have encountered a unique solution of needing to check if a value is one of four options and was wondering is it better to simply search an array or just use OR statements.
Specifically for this project I am forced to use Strings/chars instead of int

Also if its not much trouble is there a better way to search?

Also since I am only using the string arrays to store 1 number, would it be more efficient/understandable to change it to char?

example 1

```
String number = 6;

if (number == "0" || number == "2" || number == "6" || number == "8")
{
   System.out.println("TRUE");
}
```

example 2
import java.util.Arrays;

```
String[] myList = {0, 2, 6, 8};
String number = 6;

if (Arrays.stream(myList).anyMatch(number::equals))
{
   System.out.println("TRUE");
}
```

Comment: thats not a function. Thats a logical operator

Comment: Also, dont use == for String comparisons.  Use `.equals()`

Comment: That doesnt look like it should compile without an error. Why are you assigning int literals to a String variable and inside a String[]?

Comment: In any case at this level, any sort of optimization you do would probably be premature optimization and really not worth the time and effort put into thinking about it if you do not know whats going on at a deeper level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format multiple 'or' conditions in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604814/how-to-format-multiple-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use arrays with a stream as that incurs unnecessary overhead. You might consider using a `Set<String>` to hold the digits.  This will work pretty much in constant time.

```
Set<String> digits = Set.of("0", "2", "6", "8"};

String number = "6";
System.out.println(digits.contains(number) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

or you could use a switch statement.

```
number = "9";
String result = switch(number) {
    case "0","2","6","8" ->"TRUE";
    default -> "FALSE";
};

System.out.println(result);
```

But for a small number of values, there is nothing wrong using `||`